# Button Styling CSS - Issue with I.E

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have this styling for a **button**. Working **perfect** on **Firefox** and **Chrome**, but not with **Internet Explorer (ALL VERSIONS)**

**JsFiddle DEMO :** http://jsfiddle.net/Mhded/1/

Here is my Code :

**HTML:**

```
<span class="button_style">Comment</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.button_style { 
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#006666 0%,#006666 100%);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#006666),color-stop(100%,#006666));
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#006666 0%,#006666 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#006666 0%,#006666 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#006666 0%,#006666 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(top,#006666 0%,#006666 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#006666',endColorstr='#006666',GradientType=0);
    border: 1px solid #006666;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Helvetica',sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 70px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: What exactly wrong with IE? And do you really mean all versions (IE 1 - IE 11)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This here works for me in IE10](http://jsfiddle.net/sKNzk/1/)

[This works in IE8+, (Not tested on IE8 down) - uses background colour rather than gradient](http://jsfiddle.net/tCnre/)

I added `border:none;` and it stopped displaying a border around it and looks like this in IE10:

[Button screenshot http://puu.sh/4ucGX.png](http://puu.sh/4ucGX.png)

and this in IE8 (Border radius is not supported in IE8-)

[image: IE8 button]

IE9 and down doesn't show anything since you're using gradients. You can (kind of) fix it by just adding `background:#006666` since you don't need a gradient from one colour into the same colour with no difference in between.

Comment: Sorry for the repeated edits, but the answer looks better if you inline the image

Comment: Thank you @Bojangles, I didn't know how to do it!

Comment: Why is my post down rated ? What have i done wrong ? I guess this was a fair and straight forward question

Comment: No idea why it was down voted, I've up voted so it's reset back to 0 :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because IE doesn't support some of your CSS **properties**. You need to research each one and find out how to do it for IE.

Filter is one that is not supported in IE 10 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801215(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Lets try to use proper terms: CSS doesn't have attributes, `filter` is a property.